# How can I redirect multiple pages in Navbar component on React Js without triggering the 'useNavigate()' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to handle this error in react js

```
Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
Navbar
C:/Users/dell/OneDrive/Desktop/ReactJs/react-learning/src/components/Navbar.js:9
   6 | import { Routes , Route , useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
   7 | 
   8 | export default function Navbar() {
>  9 |   const navigate = useNavigate();
  10 | 
  11 |   const navigateToExperience =() =>{
  12 |     navigate('/experience');
```

I try to redirect the multiple page in navbar.

Code:

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes , Route , useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToExperience =() =>{
    navigate('/experience');
  };
  const navigateToProjects =() =>{
    navigate('/projects');
  };
  const navigateToEducation =() =>{
    navigate('/education');
  };
  const navigateToSkills =() =>{
    navigate('/skills');
  };
  const navigateToContact =() =>{
    navigate('/contact');
  };
  const navigateToAbout =() =>{
    navigate('/about');
  };
  return (
   
    <div>
      <nav
        className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
        id="fitnav"
      >
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            Shivam Curriculum vitae
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="/navbarText"
            aria-controls="navbarText"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbarCenter">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToExperience}>
                  Experience
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/experience" element={<experience/>} />
                </Routes>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToProjects}>
                  Projects
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<projects/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToEducation}>
                  Education
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<education/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToSkills}>
                  Skills
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<skills/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToAbout}>
                  About Us
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<about/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href={navigateToContact}>
                  Contact Us
                </a>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<contact/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <span className="navbar-text">
              My All Skills and Projects are show here!!
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

  );
}
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Intro from "./components/Intro";
import Education from "./components/Education";
import Project from "./components/Project";
import Contactform from "./components/Contactform";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import img1 from "./images/profilepic.jpg";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <body>
        <div className="navcolor">
        <Navbar />
        </div>
        <div className="mainpostion">
          <div className="postion">
            <img src={img1} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="postion2">
            <Intro />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <Education />
        </div>
        <div className="container-mb-3">
          <div className="projecthead">
            <h1>Our Projects And Discription ... </h1>
          </div>
          <Project />
        </div>

        <div className="container" id="adjust">
          <h1>Contact us for Hireing me ..</h1>
          <Contactform />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Move `Navbar` into a router so there's a provided routing context. If you need more help can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the relevant code causing the error?

Comment: how can you give the example

Comment: How about you show us your code? How would we give an example without it?

Answer (score 1):

The `useNavigate` hook can only be used within the routing context provided by a router, e.g. `BrowserRouter`, etc. Move `Navbar` such that it is rendered under a router component. In this case the `App` component imports a router and renders its content into it.

Example App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>   // <-- provides routing context
      <body>
        <div className="navcolor">
          <Navbar />  // <-- uses `useNavigate` hook which consumes routing context
        </div>
        ...
      </body>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Since you need only one router (*and routing context*) per React app, it's common to render the router at the root, wrapping the `App` component.

Example index.js:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Additionally, the `Navbar` component should be rendering the `Link` component instead of raw anchor tags (`<a>`). In doing so there's no need to use the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` functions and callbacks. The routes should probably not be rendered in the navbar, but out in the content area in `App`.

Navbar

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav
        className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
        id="fitnav"
      >
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Shivam Curriculum vitae
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="/navbarText"
            aria-controls="navbarText"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbarCenter">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/experience">
                  Experience
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/projects">
                  Projects
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/education">
                  Education
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/skills">
                  Skills
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">
                  About Us
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">
                  Contact Us
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <span className="navbar-text">
              My All Skills and Projects are show here!!
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <body>
        <div className="navcolor">
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={/* Home page content */} />
          <Route path="/experience" element={<Experience />} />
          <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
          <Route path="/education" element={<Education />} />
          <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>

        <div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your error "useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a  component" arises because the `useNavigate` hook can only be used within components that are descendants of a `BrowserRouter` or `Router` component. The `Router` component is what provides the context that `useNavigate` needs to function.

Additionally, in your current code you're trying to pass a function to href which is incorrect. The `href` attribute expects a string value. Instead of this, you should make use of `onClick` event to handle the navigation upon clicking.

Here's how you could modify your `Navbar` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="fitnav">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
            Shivam Curriculum vitae
          </a>
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbarCenter">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/experience")}>
                Experience
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/projects")}>
                Projects
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/education")}>
                Education
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/skills")}>
                Skills
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/about")}>
                About Us
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" onClick={() => navigate("/contact")}>
                Contact Us
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <span className="navbar-text">
            My All Skills and Projects are show here!!
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Remember, for this to work properly, your `Navbar` component should be rendered as a child of a `BrowserRouter` or `Router` component. Typically, this is done in your top-level `App` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      {/* Your routes here */}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `Routes` and `Route` components should be also wrapped within a `BrowserRouter` or `Router` component. This is typically done in your main `App` component where you define the main routes of your application.